# How to open a particular file from a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora

How do I open a file from a terminal? When I try to open a simple `.txt` file:

```
open _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt
```

I get this message:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Have I used the wrong command? Or do you use different commands to open different file types?

Comment: What do you mean by opening it?  Do you want to edit it?  You can use nano, emacs or vi for that.

Comment: Sounds like you're coming from a Mac, where `open` does the same as double-clicking would in the Desktop.

Comment: That question can't be serious.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `xdg-open` to open files in a terminal.

From the man-page of `xdg-open`:

> **xdg-open** - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application

**Usage**

The command `xdg-open _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt` will open the text file in a text editor that is set to handle text files. The command will also work with other common file extensions, opening the file with the relevant application.

See also:

- [How can I open a file in my terminal, like nautilus does it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157942/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-my-terminal-like-nautilus-does-it)

Comment: If you struggle to remember `xdg-open` like I often do, add `alias open=xdg-open` to your `~/.bashrc` file. Then, run `source ~/.bashrc` and now you can use `open` instead of `xdg-open`.

Comment: or for a windows user - alias start=xdg-open :-)

Answer (score 5):

You must use an editor to open a text file:

Any of those can do it:

```
 - vi _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt
 - vim _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt
 - emacs _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt
 - nano _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt
 - gedit _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt (gnome's default editor)
 - leafpad _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt (lxde's default editor)
 - kedit _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt (KDE's default editor)
```

Or if you wanted to just view the file without modifying its contents: `cat _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt`

**EDIT #1:** I just noticed that the question is tagged ***fedora***, which up until now is using gnome as its core graphical user interface, which comes with **gedit** preinstalled. So this is guaranteed to work: `gedit _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You should use an appropriate application to open it - try `nano _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt` or `cat  _b2rR6eU9jJ.txt`. The former will edit, the latter will output it to standard output. (Note - you can replace nano with vi, emacs or other text editor of your preference)

From what I can tell

```
geek@ubuntu:~$ open --help
open: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: openvt [-c vtnumber] [-f] [-l] [-u] [-s] [-v] [-w] -- command_line
```

open refers to openvt - and the man page describes it as `openvt - start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).` You're trying to open a text file, so unless I'm missing something, it isn't the software for doing what you want to do.